# How can I apply Boolean AND operator in YouTube API v3 search operation?

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I want to apply Boolean AND operation on the search query.
Example: q=India AND Food

The official documentation only mentions about OR and NOT operators.

> The q parameter specifies the query term to search for.
>   Your request can also use the Boolean NOT (-) and OR (|) operators to exclude videos or to find videos that are associated with one of several search terms. For example, to search for videos matching either "boating" or "sailing", set the q parameter value to boating|sailing. Similarly, to search for videos matching either "boating" or "sailing" but not "fishing", set the q parameter value to boating|sailing -fishing. Note that the pipe character must be URL-escaped when it is sent in your API request. The URL-escaped value for the pipe character is %7C.

Is there any tip or workaround to apply AND?

Thanks.

Comment: wild guess try ,  if it works you might want to send in a bug report.

Comment: @DaImTo "wild guess try??". I am not getting what are you trying to say. please elaborate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Comma (,) appears to be the *and* in Youtube searching

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&maxResults=25&q=surfing%2Ccat&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

I tested this using the [query explorer](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/youtube/v3/youtube.search.list?part=snippet&maxResults=25&q=surfing%252Ccat&_h=1&)  *I have reported this as a bug in the documentation.*

```
  {
   "kind": "youtube#searchResult",
   "etag": "\"cbz3lIQ2N25AfwNr-BdxUVxJ_QY/yGHykgbj2os5tUgCZrcquXy09YM\"",
   "id": {
    "kind": "youtube#video",
    "videoId": "XNR_wrAaoqA"
   },
   "snippet": {
    "publishedAt": "2016-03-10T14:00:01.000Z",
    "channelId": "UCqhnX4jA0A5paNd1v-zEysw",
    "title": "GoPro: Didga the Dog-Surfing Cat",
    "description": "Didga takes it from the park to the pool to cool off with his canine companion, Ice, in sunny Australia. See more of Didga here: ...",
    "thumbnails": {
     "default": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/XNR_wrAaoqA/default.jpg",
      "width": 120,
      "height": 90
     },
     "medium": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/XNR_wrAaoqA/mqdefault.jpg",
      "width": 320,
      "height": 180
     },
     "high": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/XNR_wrAaoqA/hqdefault.jpg",
      "width": 480,
      "height": 360
     }
    },
    "channelTitle": "GoPro",
    "liveBroadcastContent": "none"
   }
```

Comment: @DalmTo, I don't think this is working either. I searched comma separated values on Youtube itself, but it is not 100% accurate. Somewhat 70-75% accurate results are there.

I tried this: https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=waterproof%2Cankita

Comment: maybe that's becouse there are no videos with waterproof and cankita.   Remember the API does not work 100% the same as the YouTube Website.  The website searches in more fields than the api does.   You will never get the exact same results.   Try Surfing,cat  you get results with both.   If it didnt work you would get an error or it would return results for the word "surfing,cat" as all the text exactly like that.   Its not its returning results with surfing and cat   Also if memory serves it only searches title not description.

Comment: Can you please help me resolve this problem I have posted here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47593438/youtube-api-v3-returning-400-error-when-using-pagetoken

Answer (score 0):

For AND, I think you can just put both keywords in the search, it will act like AND.

But for OR operator, it seems YouTube only support one OR operator in each search. When you put 2 and more OR in query, it will return nothing.